# non-numeric argument to binary operator when both elements are numeric

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the dataframe below:

```
         Left N_l N_b UG  S    m    A   x.sqr  e_1  e_2  e_3 e_4 e_5
4   0.4069340   1   5 84  9   1.20  -9   810  14.6  0.0  0.0   0   0
120 0.5685562   4   5 84 15   0.65 -15  2250  29.0 17.0  5.0  -7   0
91  0.4726100   3   5 84  9   0.85  -9   810  14.6  2.6 -9.4   0   0
12  0.4725147   1   5 84 12   1.20 -12  1440  21.8  0.0  0.0   0   0
44  0.6616817   2   5 84 12   1.00 -12  1440  21.8  9.8  0.0   0   0
14  0.5244497   1   5 84 15   1.20 -15  2250  29.0  0.0  0.0   0   0
41  0.7095916   2   5 84 15   1.00 -15  2250  29.0 17.0  0.0   0   0

> class(DATA.GIRDER1$N_l)
[1] "numeric"
> class(DATA.GIRDER1$N_b)
[1] "numeric"
```

I try to apply the function `R` to the dataframe but I get the error: Error in N_l/N_b : non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l <- x["N_l"]
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr <- x["x.sqr"]
  m <- x["m"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  ee <- e[e != 0]
  f <- m * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(ee,N_l,sum) / x.sqr))
  return(max(f))
}

DATA.GIRDER1 <- cbind(DATA.GIRDER1, Proposed.Girder1 = (apply(DATA.GIRDER1, 1, R)))
```

**EDITED**

After the edit based on the answers, the dataframe was converted to numeric:

```
DATA.GIRDER1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(DATA.GIRDER1,as.numeric))

R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l <- x[as.numeric("N_l")]
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr <- x["x.sqr"]
  m <- x["m"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  ee <- e[e != 0]
  if(length(ee) >= N_l) max(m * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(ee,N_l,sum) / x.sqr))) else 0
}

apply(DATA.GIRDER1, 1, R)
```

**The new error is : Error in if (length(ee) >= N_l) max(m * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(ee, N_l,  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

Comment: It is because all the values are 0 and there are no elements left with `ee`.  What do you want to return in that case?

Comment: I didn't mention `as.data.frame(sapply(DATA.GIRDER1,as.numeric))`.  My code was `DATA.GIRDER1[sapply(DATA.GIRDER1, is.numeric)]`

Comment: The issue with `sapply` to convert to `numeric` is also that it is first converting to `matrix`.  instead it would be `lapply(DATA.GIRDER1, as.numeric)` and here `as.numeric may not work if the column value is 'S125' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `length` of 'ee' is 0 because there are no elements that are not equal to 0.  We could create a condition to check for the `length` and if it is greater than 0 only do the `max`

```
R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l <- x["N_l"]
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr <- x["x.sqr"]
  m <- x["m"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  ee <- e[e != 0]
  if(length(ee) >= N_l) max(m * ((N_l/N_b) + (A * combn(ee,N_l,sum) / x.sqr))) else 0
  
}

apply(DATA.GIRDER1, 1, R)
#  4  6  7 18 21 22 
#  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

#### Update

Based on the updated data, it is loooping over the rows of the dataset where the data also have some non-numeric column.  The `apply` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single type resulting in `character` class.  THe solution would be to either subset the numeric columns or convert to `numeric` inside

```
apply(DATA.GIRDER1[sapply(DATA.GIRDER1, is.numeric)], 1, R)
```

-output

```
#     4        120         91         12         44         14         41 
#0.04533333 0.32933333 0.43633333 0.02200000 0.13666667 0.23200000 0.09333333
```

Comment: I do not think that is the source of the error, I just updated the dataframe to resolve that issue and chose some random rows to show a better distribution of numbers. I still run to the same exact error.

Comment: @MaralDorri I understand the issue.  You are looping over the whole dataset where it have non-numeric columns as well.  With `apply`, it converts to matrix and matrix can have a single type

Comment: So You suggest I remove the columns with the non-numeric values?

Comment: I am getting a different error now..."Error in if (m < 0) stop("m < 0", domain = NA) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: @MaralDorri is it based on the same example.  Ok, it is from the `combn`.  I would use a condition i.e. `if(length(ee) > N_l)`

Comment: but the length of ee is always equal to N_l, that is how i define ee previously. I am not exactly sure how to incorporate the condition you are talking about. would that be within the `combn` function?

Comment: @MaralDorri this is what is happening for the function `combn(1:2, 4)#
Error in combn(1:2, 4) : n < m`

Comment: I tried the updated function and i still get the same error...

Comment: @MaralDorri can you please update an example that shows the error as I am not getting it

Comment: @MaralDorri it is working for me `apply(DATA.GIRDER1[sapply(DATA.GIRDER1, is.numeric)], 1, R)#    
         4        120         91         12         44         14         41 
0.04533333 0.32933333 0.43633333 0.02200000 0.13666667 0.23200000 0.09333333`